# Parsing mysql output into bash variables is broken by white spaces

Tags: mysql, bash, mariadb

I want to read all rows in a table and put them in individual variables in bash, but I'm having a problem when the cell entries have white spaces in them:

```
while read id name neighbourhood city
do
        echo "ID: $id"
        echo "name: $name"
        echo "neighbourhood: $neighbourhood"
        echo "city: $city"
        echo -e "\n"
done < <(echo "SELECT id, name, neighbourhood_id, city_id FROM households" | mysql -u kong -pHarald city_planner -h 0)
```

If the `name` is just a single word it all looks fine, but if it has three individual words separated by white space, it ends up as shown below:

```
...

ID: 200
name: Durek
neighbourhood: 1
city: 2


ID: 201
name: Kong
neighbourhood: Harald
city: Rex   1   2

...
```

How can I make the whole name end up in the name variable?

Comment: try adding `IFS=` , `while IFS= read ....`

Comment: That is asking for too many problems -- there are a lot of special characters in Shells and in MySQL -- you are asking for corruption if one of those echos turns into multiple statements such as `rm`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you only have one string with whitespaces you can put them at the last position

```
root@localhost:~# while read id neighbourhood city name
> do
>         echo "ID: $id"
>         echo "name: $name"
>         echo "neighbourhood: $neighbourhood"
>         echo "city: $city"
>         echo -e "\n"
> done < <(echo "SELECT id, neighbourhood_id, city_id, name FROM households" | mysql -u root Bernd -N)
ID: 200
name: Durek
neighbourhood: 1
city: 2


ID: 201
name: Kong Harald Rex
neighbourhood: 1
city: 2


root@localhost:~#
```

Answer (score 0):

I suggest to use  "CONCAT" first and then "IFS" for while loop, like this:

```
while IFS='@' read -r id name neighbourhood city
do
    echo "ID: $id"
    echo "name: $name"
    echo "neighbourhood: $neighbourhood"
    echo "city: $city"
    echo -e "\n"

done < <( mysql -u kong -pHarald city_planner -h 0 -NBe "SELECT CONCAT(id, '@', name, '@', neighbourhood_id, '@', city_id ) FROM households")
```